# Android: Add custom view for tabs (TabLayout with ViewPager) dynamically

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am implementing `TabLayout` with `ViewPager` where no of tabs are not fixed and gets increased as user scrolls the page. I have to also implement custom view for each `TabLayout.Tab`. I am trying to setup `TabLayout` using following snippet.

```
 private void setupTabLayout() {
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        View v = adapter.getTabView(i, true);
        tab.setCustomView(v);
    }


    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.setCustomView(adapter.getTabView(tab.getPosition(), true));
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

Following is custom view for tab

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:id="@+id/month"
    android:text="SEP"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:text="21"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Following is layout for `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`

```
         <LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />
</ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Initially when app is opened, tabs are setup properly and are visible properly. But, then when I dynamically add more tabs and scroll, custom views for tab doesn't get updated. Please help me with adding custom views for dynamically added tabs.

Comment: what is the content of tabs?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: your custom view contains text and icon or what? do you make a layout for customView?